# XBAP - FullTrust deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, certificate, clickonce, xbap

I have an XBAP app that I would like to publish. This app requires FullTrust, so I need to sign it.

I can do that and publish the app. However clients who do not have my certificate cannot install/run the app, they would have to install the certificate before doing that.
Is there a way to avoid or automate it? Either embed the certificate installation within the deployment (Click-once) or maybe sign the app use service like VerySign (e.g.)?

Is SSL a topic that might help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to sign the clickonce using a certificate from a trusted certificate authority such as Verisign as you suggest. Otherwise you'll need the users to distribute the certificate you've generated to your users and have them install it on their local machines.